# swift how to update first controller from logic in second one vai protocol and delegate pattern?

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols, delegation

I have a label in first view controller ViewController, and a func getting date avery second in second vc. I'd like to update label in first after timer starts in second. is it good to use protocol-delegate pattern? at this moment it is not working, time is going but not updating the view in first VC

my struct for protocol

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate: class {        
    func changeLabelText(textToPass: String)        
}
```

in first viewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var mainLabel: UILabel!        

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
    }


    func changeLabelText(textToPass: String) {
        self.mainLabel.text = textToPass
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {            

        let nextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        nextVC.delegateSubscriber = self            
        present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)            
    }

}
```

in secondVC

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: speed timer feature 1/3
    private weak var timer: Timer?
    private var timerDispatchSourceTimer : DispatchSourceTimer?

    weak var delegateSubscriber : ViewControllerDelegate?       

    @IBOutlet weak var myTxtField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        startTimer(every: 1)            
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        print("appeared")
        stopTimer()

    }

    private func startTimer(every timeInterval: TimeInterval) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in

                let dateToPass = Date().description
                print(dateToPass)
                self?.delegateSubscriber?.changeLabelText(textToPass: dateToPass)

            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: speed timer feature 3/3
    private func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        //timerDispatchSourceTimer?.suspend() // if you want to suspend timer
        timerDispatchSourceTimer?.cancel()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

//        delegateSubscriber?.changeLabelText(textToPass: self.myTxtField.text ?? "error")

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `[weak self]` from `Timer` closure

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
    let dateToPass = Date().description
    print(dateToPass)
    self.delegateSubscriber?.changeLabelText(textToPass: dateToPass)
}
```

*... then `self` isn't optional*

Comment: oh! in fact I was wondering why self needed to be chained or checked. you solved, but could you help me ton understand better your solution?

Comment: @biggreentree I'm not sure if I can provide you the best explanation, so I can refer you to one good article https://blog.bobthedeveloper.io/swift-retention-cycle-in-closures-and-delegate-836c469ef128

Comment: @biggreentree but I think, once you've marked your delegate as `weak` you don't have to use `weak` reference to your ViewController

Comment: Maybe I understood, but now the "stopTimer" func is not working, just like I'm not using the sea secondVC instance. maybe it is related to the [weak self] matter.

Comment: @biggreentree where are you calling `stopTimer`

Comment: tried in viewWillAppear or adding an if test linked to a isTestGoingVar. viewWillAppear is called, but timer is not stopping

Comment: wouldn't be better to stop timer in `viewWillDisappear` every time when user leave second ViewController?

Comment: no, since I activate the timer in secondVC, but I see its effect in fitsVC, If I put stopTimer in viewWillDisappear it will be unusefull what we have done. I'd like to stop timer only if I access again to secondVC, in order to start it again

Comment: Has this any effect? `SecondViewController().timer?.invalidate()`

Comment: tested in secondVC viewWillAppear, same issue.

Comment: @biggreentree what about this: keep `[weak self]` and remove `weak` keyword before delegate variable